# Suggestion on how to store user private key using AuthKitBasePack

Tags: gnosis-safe

I see that Safe provides a Web3AuthModalPack where you use Web3Auth to store user-key mapping.

If we would like to implement our own `AuthModal extends AuthKitBasePack` with Google login, I guess the processes are below:

1. login the user using Google => get the Google user id
2. map the Google user id against some kinds of database to check for key pair
3. if the user-key mapping exists then return the user-key mapping
4. else generate a key pair and store user with this key pair

In step 4, I wonder where and how we can store this mapping. If we store it in our backend server likes what Web3Auth does, it's nothing but to reinvent the wheel, right?

The reason we don't want to use Web3Auth, is to provide our user a real self-custody wallet.

Any recommendation would be very appreciated.